# windows phone data binding listpicker to List of Strings

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-phone

I have a list of strings that initializes in the constructor:

```
public List<String> m_Distances = new List<String>();
public List<String> Distances
{
    get
    {
        return m_Distances;
    }
}
```

and also in the constructor:

```
listPickerDistance.ItemsSource = Distances;
```

Now in my XAML:

```
                <TextBlock Text="Distance" x:Name="textBlockDistance"/>
                <toolkit:ListPicker ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="listPickerDistance">
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Distances, ElementName=listPickerDistanceSearch}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </toolkit:ListPickerItem>
                </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Can you please help me bind the list to the listpicker?
Should be easy.. isn't it?

Comment: Your XAML overrides the ItemsSource you set in your constructor.

Comment: Yes.. I tried to remove that (in the second line of my XAML).. still doesn't work..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is all:

```
public List<String> m_Distances = new List<String>();
public List<String> Distances
{
    get
    {
        return m_Distances;
    }
}

listPickerDistance.ItemsSource = Distances;

<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="listPickerDistance">

</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Comment: DataTemplate is only necessary when you are binding to a class or want to customize the layout.