# How to convert string list to observable collection in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Hi all i have a list string like

```
 List<string> numbers=new List<string>();
```

now i want to convert it on observable collection i have converted it successfully like

```
ObservableCollection<string> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>(numbers);
```

but when i am deleting a item from list box like

```
myCollection.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
        listBox1.ItemsSource = myCollection;
```

the above code is deleted all the item in list box but i want to delete specific item in list box.

Comment: `ObservableCollection<string> numbers=new ObservableCollection<string>();` tada

Comment: Will  sir it is not possible b'coz numbers is already contains in List<string> numbers=new List<string>();

Comment: Change it.  ObservableCollection implements IList.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Delete Item from Observable collection in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30567951/how-to-delete-item-from-observable-collection-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Initialize collection and lsitbox

```
 List<string> numbers=new List<string>();
 //numbers.Add("test");  //populate list

  ObservableCollection<string> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>(numbers);
  listBox1.ItemsSource = myCollection;
```

now use the below code to remove the selected item from the list

```
var selectedItem =listbox1.SelectedItem as string;
if(myCollection.Contains(selectedItem)
   {
      myCollection.Remove(selectedItem);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding `ObservableCollection` you can directly bind `List<string>`  to your **listBox1.ItemsSource**. See this example to bind `List<string>`

[windows phone data binding listpicker to List of Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955960/windows-phone-data-binding-listpicker-to-list-of-strings)

To remove items from list try this

```
listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: Thank you guys i have solve my problem
       numbers.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);

            listBox1.ItemsSource = null;

            listBox1.ItemsSource = numbers;

Answer (score 0):

Answer_:
     numbers.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);

```
        listBox1.ItemsSource = null;

        listBox1.ItemsSource = numbers;
```